# St-cytoscape update graph after data change

Tags: python, streamlit, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I use streamlit and use st-cytoscape to visualize my graph.
Code I have:

```
import streamlit as st
from st_cytoscape import cytoscape
stylesheet = [
    {
        "selector": "node",
        "style": {
            "label": "data(display_text)",
            "width": 20,
            "height": 20,
            "font-size": 13
        },
    },
    {
        "selector": ".colorarrow",
        "style": {
            "background-color": "#fcba03"
        }
    },
    {
        "selector": "edge",
        "style": {
            "width": 3,
            "curve-style": "bezier",
            'line-color': 'grey'
        },
    },
]
graph_data = all_unique_nodes + edges
layout = {"name": "preset", "animationDuration": 0}
selected = cytoscape(
        graph_data,
        stylesheet,
        layout=layout,
        key="graphx",
)
# After selecting some nodes, give selected colors for example the color red
# This can only be done changing the graph_data, but how can I update the graph without making a new one.
```

Expecting: manipulate data and update graph but not possible with this library I think.

Comment: This code snippet is not runnable as-is. You can use st.empty to replace an element in-place: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.empty